# Is there a way in VS 2010 with TFS 2008 to check in your changes as a new branch?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, branching-and-merging

My question is rather simple I have made many changes in our project which I don't want to merge with the main branch right away. I did not take a branch at the start of these changes while I was making them. So now I tried to find a way to take branch to check in my code but there does not seem to be a solution. How can I do this and what is the best approach to take. I am using Visual Studio 2010 which connects to TFS 2008.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could create a new branch now and then change the paths on your edited files to the new branch before checking them in.

1. Create a new branch.
2. Shelve your pending changes.
3. Use the power tools to move the shelved changes from the current branch to your new branch using the following command.

   tfpt unshelve [MY_SHELVESET_NAME] /migrate /source:CURRENT_BRANCH_PATH /target:NEW_BRANCH_PATH

Take a look at the powertools help to get further details.

Comment: I am not sure why but I was not able to shelve my current changes hence can not try your solution. I will try to solve&understand why I cannot shelve than comment back. Thank you for your help Kaius.

Edit: That was because I am a total noob(Did not see the shelve name part) I am trying your solution right away.

Comment: ok, once you run the command the paths on the unshelved files should match your new branch. Test and build everything before checking in but you should be good to go at that stage.

Comment: Well probably because I am a beginner I was not able to get past the "unable to determine workspace" problem. Out TFS is on a server and if I use the command on my computer at the correct folder it says it was not able to reach the server. (404)

Comment: Ok the reason you are gettng an "unable to determine workspace" error message is because you are running the command from a location that is not within a TFS controlled directory.  You need to move to the directory where your code is stored and run the command again.  The 404 error is something else, you generally get that when the tfs client cannot connect to the TFS server. You will need to supply more information.  

At this stage if its not working and the number of changes are small it might be worth recreating the changes under the new branch manually instead?

Comment: Well thank you very much for all your effort I was not able to do the way you described but I will mark your entry as answer, problems were about me after all. I did solve my problem through getting a normal branch, getting it and overwriting everything with new ones. It did caused some problems but get the job done. Thank you for your kind help again.

Comment: I was able to follow your instructions and get my stuff merged.  I can't believe how much time you've saved me. Thank you so much.